# Plus operator problems in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying with following script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#item1_number_1').keyup(function() {
            var valone = $('#item1_number_1').val();
            var valtwo = 5;
            var total = ((valone) + (valtwo));
            $('#item2_number_1').val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I do not get any result in the field. But when I assign multiple (*) instead of plus (+), I am getting result.

I cannot understand what the error is in "var total = ((valone) + (valtwo));"

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt()` to convert fetched  value(`valone` ) to number, and calculate, something like this, please use this only when your number is not float(`56.66`),

```
var valone =  parseInt($('#item1_number_1').val(), 10);
var valtwo = 5;
var total = ((valone) + (valtwo));
```

The fetched vaue is treated like string until you convert it into number.

**UPDATE**

After **Archer** pointed out, I came to know you are using `toFixed()` method, which supposed to expect float numbers. So in this case you should use `parseFloat()` as given below.

```
 var valone = parseFloat($('#item1_number_1').val());
```

Comment: @downvoter can you please notify what is the mistake that I can fix?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I consider this incorrect as it will only work with whole numbers.  The OP's use of `toFixed()` suggests that they're expecting the numbers to not necessarily be integers.  If you were to change `parseInt()` to `parseFloat()` then I'd happily balance the -1 with a +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

You can only call `toFixed` on Numbers.

`String * String` will convert the strings to Numbers and **multiply** them giving you a `Number`.

`String + String` will **concatenate** the two Strings together giving you a `String`.

You need to convert the strings to Numbers manually before you try to add them together.

```
var total = (+valone) + (+valtwo);
```

Then `Number + Number` will **add** the two Numbers together giving you a Number.

Comment: +1 The only answer that takes into account that his use of `toFixed` suggests that the first value may not be an int.

Comment: @Archer Erm, excuse me then.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol But your answer parses the input as an integer :s

Comment: @Archer Ah, I understand now. Funnily enough I actually considered it, but didn't write it XD `parseFloat` would, of course, be more suitable in this case than `parseInt`... -edits-

Answer (score 2):

The value of an input is always a string. "Adding" a string concatenates, giving another string. Strings do not have a `toFixed` method.

`*` however is unambiguously "multiply", giving a number and therefore a result.

```
var valone = parseFloat(document.getElementById('item1_number_1').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of them is a string. Try `parseInt(valone)` to make it an int first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `+` operator can also be used to concat strings together.  The `*` operator is ONLY for multiplication and therefore it implicitly converts your values to numbers.

So you either need to use `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, or `Number` to explicitly convert to a numeric type before using the `+` operator.